# KMeans in the shortest and most readable format

Tags: python, numpy, clustering

I'm learning Python (coming from Java) so I decided to write KMeans as a practice for the language. However I want to see how could one improve the code and making it shorter and yet readable.  I still find the code rather long. Also if you have comments regarding conventions or proper practices, I would really appreciate it.

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import linalg as LA

def main():
    #data = np.arange(20).reshape( (4,5) )
    file_name = "/Users/x/Desktop/tst.csv"
    with open(file_name) as f:
        ncols = len(f.readline().split(","))
    data = np.loadtxt(file_name, delimiter=",", usecols=range(0,ncols-1))
    kmeans = KMeans()
    kmeans.cluster(data, 3, 200)
    print kmeans.means


class KMeans:

    def __init__(self):
        self.means = None
        self.data_assignments = None

    #data is a 2D Numpy array       
    def cluster(self, data, numClusters, iterations):
        if numClusters < 1:
            raise Exception("The number of clusters should be larger than 0.")
        if numClusters > data.shape[0]:
            raise Exception("The number of clusters is beyond the number of rows.")

        #Pick random means
        randomMeansIndices = np.random.choice( range( data.shape[0] ), 
                                               size=numClusters, replace=False ) 

        for i in randomMeansIndices:
            if self.means is not None:
                self.means = np.vstack( ( self.means, data[ i ] ) )
            else:
                self.means = data[ i ]

        for iteration in xrange(iterations):
            #Data assignment
            self.data_assignments = {} 
            for row in data:
                distances = {}
                meanID = 0
                for mean in self.means:
                    distances[meanID] = LA.norm(mean - row)
                    meanID += 1
                nearestMean = min( distances, key=lambda x: distances[x] )
                if nearestMean in self.data_assignments:
                    self.data_assignments[nearestMean] = np.vstack( (self.data_assignments[nearestMean], row) )
                else:
                    self.data_assignments[nearestMean] = row

            #Update the means
            self.means = None
            for mean_data_matrix in self.data_assignments.values():
                if mean_data_matrix.ndim == 1:
                    mean_data_matrix = mean_data_matrix.reshape((1,-1)) #reshape to make it 2D
                if self.means is None:
                    self.means = np.mean( mean_data_matrix, axis=0 ) #the first updated mean vector
                else:
                    newMean = np.mean( mean_data_matrix, axis=0 ) #updated mean vector
                    self.means = np.vstack( (self.means, newMean) )#add an updated mean

main()
```

Comment: From a mathematical standpoint, I don't think you should raise an exception if the number of clusters is not within the number of rows. Zero clusters would result in no clustering, while having `> numRows` clusters would simply result in some of the clusters being empty. Not a cause for error.

Answer (score 2):

You use `vstack` a lot to build arrays row by row, with the additional complication of initializing the array variable to `None`, which needs a special case in your loops then. This complication could be avoided by intializing to zero-height 2D array instead, but in any case repeated `vstack` use is inefficient because it copies the array every time. Better options are:

- Collect rows in a list and `vstack` the list in the end. Good approach when you don't know the height of the array in advance.
- Initialize array to right size and assign into rows.
- Best of all, create array at once by a vectorized operation.

For example this

```
self.means = None
for i in randomMeansIndices:
    if self.means is not None:
        self.means = np.vstack( ( self.means, data[ i ] ) )
    else:
        self.means = data[ i ]
```

could be done in one line, as you can index arrays with arrays:

```
self.means = data[randomMeansIndices]
```

This code could avoid the loop

```
distances = {}
meanID = 0
for mean in self.means:
    distances[meanID] = LA.norm(mean - row)
    meanID += 1
nearestMean = min( distances, key=lambda x: distances[x] )
```

by computing all the norms at once (NumPy 1.8 required). `argmin` gives the index of the minimum.

```
distances = LA.norm(self.means - row, axis=1)
nearestMean = np.argmin(distances)
```

---

The `KMeans` class has no purpose other than holding the result of clustering. The `cluster` method could be a stand-alone function instead and just `return means, data_assignments`. If you prefer to access the two items by name, use a `collections.namedtuple` as the return value.